# Colors aren't showing in the “Shop By Color”

Tags: magento-1.9

Im using magento 1.9
i have added Configurable Product in magento with 3 diff. swatches,but when I go to category,I notice that colors aren't present.
im adding some screenshots here.

[image: Configurable Product]

[image: category page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have configure the color swatch wrongly Or may be some extension way that you are not using.

For default magento swatch you can follow below link, and see how you can configure and create swatches

http://www.magetraining.com/blog/how-to-set-up-configurable-swatches-in-magento-versions-1-9-x/

https://www.sherodesigns.com/tutorial-configurable-swatches-in-magento/

Comment: i just forget to add global swatch images. i refer first link you provided it's helpfull.

Comment: @user3364665 If this answer helps you then mark as accepted so other users who has same problem take benefit  from this